# modify values in variable string with php

Tags: php, string, variables, match

Consider example:

```
$mystring = "us100ch121jp23uk12";
```

I) I want to change value of  `jp` by adding +1 so that makes the string into

```
us100ch121jp24uk12
```

suppose if 
II) Is there a way to seperate the numeric part and alphabetic part in the above string into:

```
[us , 100]
[ch,121]
[jp,24]
[us,12]
```

my code:

```
$string = "us100ch121jp23uk12";

$search_for = "us";
$pairs = explode("[]", $string); // I dont know the parameters.
foreach ($pairs as $index=>$pair)
{
    $numbers = explode(',',$pair);
    if ($numbers[0] == $search_for){

        $numbers[1] += 1; // 23 + 1 = 24
        $pairs[index] = implode(',',$numbers); //push them back
        break;
    }
}
$new_string = implode('|',$pairs);
```

**using Evan sir's suggestions**

```
$mystring = "us100ch121jp22uk12";

preg_match_all("/([A-z]+)(\d+)/", $mystring, $output);

//echo $output[0][4];


foreach($output[0] as $key=>$value) {
   // echo "[".$value."]";
   echo "[".substr($value, 0, 2).",".substr($value, 2, strlen($value) - 2)."]"."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify your string output? There could be better ways of representing the data - i.e. in an array, with key-value pairs. At least, add delimiters after each country-score pair, such as `us100&ch121&jp23&uk12` or the likes (although that is _still_ bad design).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `preg_match_all("/([A-z]+)(\d+)/", $string, $output);`, it will return an array to `$output` that contains three arrays. The first array will be country number strings (eg `'us100'`). The second will contain country strings (eg `'us'`). The third will contain the numbers (eg `'100'`).

Since the second and third arrays will have matching indexes (`$output[1][0]` will be `'us'` and `$output[2][0]` will be `'100'`), you could just cycle through those and do whatever you'd like to them.

Here is more information about [using regular expressions in PHP](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html). The site also contains information about regular expressions in general, which are a useful tool for any programmer!

Comment: hello sir, thank you, this is helping me ,but is there  a way I can cylce through them so that I can get like the second part of the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using regular expressions in PHP. See tutorial: 
http://w3school.in/w3schools-php-tutorial/php-regular-expression/

```
Function    Description
ereg_replace()  The ereg_replace() function finds for string specified by pattern and replaces pattern with replacement if found.
eregi_replace() The eregi_replace() function works similar to ereg_replace(), except that the search for pattern in string is not case sensitive.
preg_replace()  The preg_replace() function works similar to ereg_replace(), except that regular expressions can be used in the pattern and replacement input parameters.
preg_match()    The preg_match() function finds string of a pattern and returns true if pattern matches false otherwise.
Expression  Description
[0-9]   It matches any decimal digit from 0 through 9.
[a-z]   It matches any character from lowercase a through lowercase z.
[A-Z]   It matches any character from uppercase A through uppercase Z.
[a-Z]   It matches any character from lowercase a through uppercase Z.
p+  It matches any string containing at least one p.
p*  It matches any string containing zero or more p’s.
p?  It matches any string containing zero or more p’s. This is just an alternative way to use p*.
p{N}    It matches any string containing a sequence of N p’s
p{2,3}  It matches any string containing a sequence of two or three p’s.
p{2, }  It matches any string containing a sequence of at least two p’s.
p$  It matches any string with p at the end of it.
^p  It matches any string with p at the beginning of it.
[^a-zA-Z]   It matches any string not containing any of the characters ranging from a through z and A through Z.
p.p It matches any string containing p, followed by any character, in turn followed by another p.
^.{2}$  It matches any string containing exactly two characters.
<b>(.*)</b> It matches any string enclosed within <b> and </b>.
p(hp)*  It matches any string containing a p followed by zero or more instances of the sequence hp.
```

**you also can use JavaScript:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp**